# How do I add conditional product options in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, product, categories

If I have a product and would like to offer a subset of products (accessories) based on a yes/no choice by the user, what's the best way to approach it?
In a simple example, a user selects a Phone. If the user then selects YES from a “Show phone accessories” dropdown
I’d them like them to be offered a set of drop downs offering choice of accessories, e.g skins, case etc.. on that page

Can this be implemented using Magento functionality?  Or must I use an add-on/extension?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is can this be done using stock Magento functionality, then the answer is No.

You may be able to do this with somewhat stock functionality just by overriding templates with custom javascript.  I.e the 'accessories' drop down is always displayed, but hidden until the user does something.

Comment: Thank you Jared, I suppose the next question is, what extensions are available that can do this?

Comment: I don't know of any extensions that do this, but it is possible that I don't understand the expected behavior quite right.  You want a drop down on all/some products that once moved to the 'yes' position displays a list of related products/cross-sells (presumably in a modal popup or in the product details box).  Correct?

Comment: correct, here's an example (not a magento site) see what happens when you click the pre-hang option http://www.doors4home.com/p-2204-htc700-1-2.aspx

Comment: Ah ok this is different.  You are basically just selecting attributes, or child products.  I could make some recommendations in that regard but would rather do it in a different venue as to not muddy up SO.

Comment: Um, please advise me, do i need an extension like  BCP? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/better-configurable-products.html

Comment: Please contact me through my website.